# utilizar INPUT dinâmico para fazer consulta no banco

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho esse script em `html` e `jquery` que busca no banco o que o usuario escreveu no input

```
<div class="form-group col-md-8" id="dynamicDiv1" >
     <label for="categoria">Categoria</label>
     <input type="search" name="categoria[]" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="busca" placeholder="Buscar por categoria">                          
     <div class="col-md-12 rm_padding">
          <ul class="list-group">
          </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

e mostra o que vem do banco de dados nesse trecho

```
<div class="col-md-12 rm_padding">
      <ul class="list-group">
      </ul>
</div>

//Busca categoria dinamicamente
$(function () {
    $('#busca').keyup(function () {

        var pesquisa = $(this).val();
        $.post('pesquisa.php', {categoria: pesquisa}, function (r) {
            $('.list-group').html(r);
        });
    });

    $('.list-group').delegate('li', 'click', function () {

        var texto = $(this).text();
        $('#busca').val(texto);
        $('.list-group').html('');

    });

    $('body').click(function (event) {
        if (event.target.id !== 'busca') {
            $('.list-group').html('');
        }
    });
});
```

Meu problema é o input em que o usuario digita ele é dinamico ou seja  um campo sempre aparece por obrigatorio porém ele pode adicionar mais 3 campos

script para adicinar campos

```
var contador = 0;
var limite = 3;

$(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#dynamicDiv1');

    $(document).on('click', '#addInput1', function () {
        if (contador < limite) {
            $('<div id="dinamic">' +
                    '<input type="search" id="busca" required="" name="categoria[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Adicionar Categoria" /> ' +                     
                    '<div class="col-md-12 rm_padding"><ul class="list-group"></ul></div>'+
                    '<br><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm left" href="javascript:void(0)" id="remInput">' +
                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus " aria-hidden="true"></span> ' +
                    'Remover Categoria' +
                    '</a>' +
                    '</div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            contador++; // incremento do contador
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#remInput', function () {
        $('#dinamic').remove();
        if (contador > 0)
            contador--; // remover do contador tb
        return false;
    });
});
```

como faço para a pesquisa dinamica tambem funcionar nesses campos que são criados dinamicamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JQUERY DELEGATE**

O jQuery atribui um evento ao item quando chamado, ou seja, se quando o jQuery foi executado o item ainda não existia, seria impossível anexar a função `keyup` à ele.

No entanto, utilizando a função `delegate`, o elemento pai é quem atribuirá aos elementos filhos a função desejada, sempre que um novo elemento for criado:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('body').append("<p><input></p>");
});

$('body').delegate('input', 'keyup', function(){ // body é o Elemento pai de input
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<button>Adicionar</button>
  
  
</body>
```

Na tua função de BUSCA muda da seguinte forma:

```
//Busca categoria dinamicamente
$(function () {
var buscaAtual = $("#busca");
    $('body').delegate('#busca', 'keyup', function(){

        var pesquisa = $(this).val();
        buscaAtual = $(this);
        $.post('pesquisa.php', {categoria: pesquisa}, function (r) {
            $('.list-group').html(r);
        });
    });

    $('.list-group').delegate('li', 'click', function () {

        var texto = $(this).text();
        buscaAtual.val(texto);
        $('.list-group').html('');

    });

    $('body').click(function (event) {
        if (event.target.id !== 'busca') {
            $('.list-group').html('');
        }
    });
});
```

[FONTE](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: Mas no caso o retorno que vem do banco seria aplicado a todos os campos?

Comment: Desde que eles sejam filhos da tag `<body>` (o que eles vão ser) vai aplicar a todos os inputs (tu pode substituir o 'input' ali por '.form-control' ou mesmo por '#busca', mas a ideia de ter vários elementos com o mesmo ID é bem ruim)

Comment: Ai que ta o problema eu preciso que cada campo dinamico possa fazer sua pesquisa no banco

Comment: Qual o problema? A pesquisa dinâmica vai funcionar nos itens criados dinamicamente.

Comment: meu problema é que a pesquisa dinamica não funciona nos campos dinamicos

Comment: @fabricio tu entendeu minha resposta? Muda `$('#busca').keyup(function () {` por `$('body').delegate('#busca', 'keyup', function(){` que a tua busca vai funcionar nos campos dinâmicos

Comment: Desculpe não tinha entendido. Agora ela funcionou porem quando eu cliclo no resultado ele não preenche o input

Comment: É por que tu tens muitos elementos chamados #busca, tu teria que fazer assim, acrescenta esse código: `var pesquisa = $(this).val(); 
var buscaAtual = $(this);` e substitui aqui `$('#busca').val(texto);` por `buscaAtual.val(texto);`

Comment: `ReferenceError: buscaAtual is not defined[Learn More]`, esta me retornando esse erro no console. desculpe tantas perguntas é que estou arrecem comendo a aprender js

Comment: Tornei Global tua variável buscaAtual e tu pode tentar, qualquer dúvida vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53695/discussion-between-thiago-santos-and-fabricio).